# Can I open a pull request using my own repo and use my own commit logs?

Tags: git, github

I have my own repo and I'd like to open a pull request with all the commit logs I've made to a forked repo on GitHub so it shows multiple commits instead of one big commit. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: Are u asking a way to merge all those commits to a single commit then yes, there is a way

Answer (score 0):

If you want only one big commit instead of multiples commits you need to do a squash with `git rebase -i first_commit_hash`. This is going to open a your configured editor and list all the commits from the commit hash given to the lastest commit. Once there you need to change `pick` to `squash`.
After that you should have just a commit that include all your other commits.